# binary size of contract

Tags: contract-deployment

If one imports another contract and instantiates it with 'new', then I assume the binary of that imported contract must be fully included in my contract (increasing its deployment size accordingly).

If I instantiate the imported contract using an already deployed address however, does that also include that binary data into my contract when I deploy it?

How about if I don't instantiate it at all, but only use a enum or struct definition from that contract. Will the entire binary of the imported contract be added to my contract's binary?

Answer (score 0):

> If one imports another contract and instantiates it with 'new', then I assume the binary of that imported contract must be fully included in my contract (increasing its deployment size accordingly).

That's correct

> If I instantiate the imported contract using an already deployed address however, does that also include that binary data into my contract when I deploy it?

No, it doesn't. Solidity will only use the imported contract's function signatures that are used by the calling contract.

> How about if I don't instantiate it at all, but only use a enum or struct definition from that contract. Will the entire binary of the imported contract be added to my contract's binary?

No. Solidity's linker will only add actual used code to the final contract bytecode.

Comment: "And how would you do that?", maybe I didn't express myself clearly. I meant, instead of doing `ImportedContract c = new ImportedContract();` what if ImportedContract has already been deployed and I'll do `ImportedContract c = ImportedContract(contractAddress);` - will this also append the entire ImportedContract binary to my contract?

Comment: Might have sounded a bit harsh there. As for your calrification: this does not create a new contract. This line just tells that Solidity that the contract at `contractAddress` can be treated as an `ImportedContract`, and it's reference is to be stored in `c`.

Comment: Yes exactly, my question is whether in this case the binary of ImportedContract will nevertheless be appended to my contract when I deploy it.

Comment: No, it won't, as that binary is part of another contract.